# How to find only failed user details in SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: reporting-services

I want to find only failed user details, but the below query is giving duplicate records. I am not able to find a proper solution.

To find failed job details I'm using the below query:

```sql
select * from executionlog e
join catalog c on e.reportid = c.itemid
where c.name like '%reportname%'
and timestart>= '2013-04-15 09:00:00.000' 
and status <> 'rsSuccess'
```

However, the above query is giving duplicate values for a particular report.

How can I get unique details?

Note: we cannot apply `distinct` or `group by` because the table contains columns of `ntext` and `image` data types

Answer (score 2):

If you want only "failed user details" then don't select the `ntext` or `image` columns at all. That way you can do a DISTINCT normally:

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT
      --Parameters,
      --Content,
      --Property,
      --Parameter,
      InstanceName, ReportID, UserName, RequestType, Format,  TimeStart, TimeEnd, 
      TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, TimeRendering, Source, Status, ByteCount, 
      [RowCount], ItemID, Path, Name, ParentID, Type,  Intermediate, SnapshotDataID, 
      LinkSourceID,  Description, Hidden, CreatedByID, CreationDate, ModifiedByID, 
      ModifiedDate, MimeType, SnapshotLimit, PolicyID, PolicyRoot, ExecutionFlag, 
      ExecutionTime
FROM  executionlog e
JOIN  catalog c ON e.reportid = c.itemid
WHERE c.name LIKE '%reportname%'
      AND timestart>= '2013-04-15 09:00:00.000' 
      AND status <> 'rsSuccess'
```

You can even trim many more columns. Note that [doing `SELECT *` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) for many cases anyway.

If you're interested in the corresponding `ntext` and/or `image` values you can always join the `catalog` against the above subquery again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply , you cannot apply distinct due to image and ntext data types. if you keep status<>'rssucess' you will get duplicates.because many things are there under status other than  rssucess i.e rsprocessingaborted , rsdenied,rsdatabaseservererror etc.. sothat we should get duplicates for same parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment makes absolutely no sense to me (maybe a language barrier?).